# Webassembly i64 primitive type

Tags: c++, c++17, webassembly

The webassembly documentation [states](https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/syntax/types.html) that webassembly can take only following types

```
i32 | i64 | f32 | f64
```

All good but , here is a really simple test in c++ that takes 4 integers and print them.

```
void intTest(
        int32_t int32TypeArg,
        uint32_t uint32TypeArg,
        int64_t int64TypeArg,
        uint64_t uint64TypeArg
    ){
    std::cout << " int32_t     :" << to_string(int32TypeArg) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " uint32_t    :" << to_string(uint32TypeArg) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " int64_t     :" << to_string(int64TypeArg) << std::endl;
    std::cout << " uint64_t    :" << to_string(uint64TypeArg) << std::endl;


}
```

when i compile and call this test in Firefox from java script like that:

```
let js_int32_t = -1;
let js_uint32_t = 1;

let js_int64_t = -1596801628841;
let js_uint64_t = 1596801628841;



let val1 = parseInt(js_int32_t );
let val2 = parseInt(js_uint32_t );
let val3 = parseInt(js_int64_t );
let val4 = parseInt(js_uint64_t );
```

i get the following output:

```
Module._intTest( val1, val2, val3, val4);
 int32_t     :-1 
 uint32_t    :1 
 int64_t     :-3978021347401611945 
 uint64_t    :0
```

why  int64_t is 3978021347401611945 and not  "-1596801628841" ? What is going on here? I definetelly passed a type "number" form javascrypt that was the purpouse of "parseInt" method.
But what is even more supprising is that uint64_t is zero instead of "1596801628841".

Update 1-> 08. August 2020

I have created a very simple webassembly module that has only 2 methods i.e. „main“ and „intTest“

The whole code can be found here

https://github.com/courteous/wasmInt64Test

the compiled code can be found here

https://github.com/courteous/wasmInt64Test/tree/master/build/src

you can run it from the console like:

```
emrun --no_browser firefox  --verboise index.htm
```

and then in the firefox console:

```
Module._intTest( js_int32_t, js_uint32_t, js_int64_t, js_uint64_t);
```

if you want to compile the code yourself run

```
emcmake cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=WASM   ../
```

Update 2 -> 08. August 2020

using std::bitset i printed bought numbers i.e. the argument that i get i.e. int64TypeArg

```
11001000 11001011 00111010 10101001 00110111 00110100 11000101 01010111
```

and statically setting setting the number to a uint64_t variable -1596801628841;

```
11111111 11111111 11111110 10001100 00110111 00110100 11000101 01010111
```

as the user @harold mentioned there are several bits that match i.e.

```
101000110000110111001101001100010101010111
```

those are 42 bits that match.  At first i was thinking that this could be related to the largest integer that javaScript has i.e. 53 bits , but those are 42 not 53.
I really want to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: In binary, the top 32 bits of -3978021347401611945 are the same as the bottom 32 bits of 1596801628841 (the negated version of the input). That's too nice to be a coincidence, but it makes no sense to me. Anyway can you show the webasm?

Comment: @harold thank you for your reply, my wasm is 6 mb large and i think it will make sence to create a separate project to show that . give me  a minute i will upload it to github in 10 minutes.

Comment: I have tested this in chrome as well it is the same thing

Comment: @harold i place the link to the wasm file in the question

Comment: Ok well I've looked at it, but there's a ton of stuff there, it's difficult to find the relevant code

Comment: well if you do wasm-nm wasmExec.wasm  |grep -i Test  you will see that there is that method called "intTest" . It is really simple one, the code of that method is exactly  posted above.

Comment: @harold  will it help if i try to create a single separate wasm with the exact same code however containing only main and intTest method?

Comment: why are you calling [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with whats already a number? its used for string parsing...

Comment: @kmdreko with parseInt() or without does not matter you can call the method like that Module._intTest( js_int32_t, js_uint32_t, js_int64_t, js_uint64_t); You will get the same result.  My intention here was to show the type of the variable to be explicit number. But feel free to try it without parseInt.

Comment: @harold i have created a wasm module that has only the method "main" and "intTest" and it much smaller in size then the previous one, including the source code on github. Can you take a look in that ?

Answer (score 5):

OK after some time it came out that you can !!! NOT !!! pass i64 from Java Script to WASM directly without changing the type of that variable first. If we want to do that we need to compile with the flag "WASM_BIGINT" and pass the that long i64 from Java Script as the type "BigInt".
example :

```
var bigInt = BigInt(-1596801628841);
```

After that the test is working properly!  This worked only with Firefox 79.0 but did not worked with Chrome  84.0.4147.105 good blog explaining  all this is  [here](https://www.asumu.xyz/blog/) and [here](https://sauleau.com/notes/wasm-bigint.html)